Capture user interactions on a webpage
I am developing an extension where the user click a record-like button on a pop-up extension and then the extension starts to record what interactions the user makes with the webpage after this. Basically, it will record all user actions and then upon user's trigger the set of recorded actions will be automated. I don't know how to pull this off. I need help with it
I tried chrome recorder but it doesn't exactly do what i want
